# date to text in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date-formatting

In VB.NET I want to get the date in text like Microsoft Excel

eg: In MSExcel entering the date : 01/01/2013 and setting format to text it gives output 41275

How can I do this with vb.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want the [DateTime.ToOADate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method.

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt As DateTime = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2013")
        Console.WriteLine(dt.ToOADate())
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

End Module
```

From above link:

> An OLE Automation date is implemented as a floating-point number whose integral component is the number of days before or after midnight, 30 December 1899, and whose fractional component represents the time on that day divided by 24. For example, midnight, 31 December 1899 is represented by 1.0; 6 A.M., 1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25; midnight, 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.0; and 6 A.M., 29 December 1899 is represented by -1.25.

Answer (score 1):

Do a date difference

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/2013"),Cdate("01/01/1900"))-2
OUTPUT:
  -41275


DateDiff(DateInterval.Day, Cdate("01/01/1900"),Cdate("01/01/2013"))+2
OUTPUT:
  41275
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://ideone.com/pyhOlk)**

Comment: @MandeepSingh: Updated. do you a date difference

Comment: @JeremyThompson: Mark has already mentioned about it **"1 January 1900 is represented by 2.25"**